# node js twilio send sms doesn't work

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

i have this function sendsms

```
 var twiml = new MessagingResponse();

function sendsms() {
                  twiml.message("aaa");
                 console.log(twiml.toString());
                   }
```

but when i call this function inside User.findone

```
 User.findOne({}, function(err, user) {
                 if (condition) {
                     sendsms();
                 }
             })
```

it log the twiml.toString successfully 
[image]
but the sms is not sent 
[image]
when i call outside user.findOne the sms is sent  successfully

```
sendsms()
```

this is the routes to send sms

```
router.post('/sendSMS', function(req, res) {
    var phone = req.body.phone;



    User.findOne({}, function(err, user) {


            require('../config/sendSMS')(user, phone);

            res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'message sent successfully' });

        }

    });
```

this is the route to get and replay to sms

```
router.post('/getSMS', function(req, res) {

    require('../config/getAndReplay')(req, res);

});
```

Comment: Can you share more of the code that isn't working. When you say "i call this function inside User.findone it dosen't work" how are you calling it? Can you show the code.

Comment: I assume this is code that is in an express application, or similar, responding to an incoming request. Can you share the whole route/action?

Comment: i did add the route/action thank you so much

Comment: OK, and what is inside `../config/sendSMS` and `../config/getAndReplay`?

Comment: the send is working perfectly the getandreplay contain the code in the top in my console when call the sendsms inside user.findone it log the twimltostring successfully but the sms is not sent when call sendsms by itself outside user.findone it work and it send sms successfully

Comment: Hold on, are you trying to initiate an SMS using TwiML?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean

Comment: What should your `/sendSMS` route do?

Comment: to initiate the conversation i sent the first sms in this route client.message.create
`var client = new twilio(config.accountSid, config.authToken);
        senarios.main(flowchart, function(routenode) {
            var msg = routenode.msg
            client.messages.create({
                body: msg,
                to: phone,
                from: '+17862071613' //the twilio web application 
            }).then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
        })`

Comment: I'm lost now. Could you try rewording your question including what you are trying to achieve and what is going wrong? Include the code along with it. Thanks

Comment: it is to simple when i call sendsms inside user.findone it log the twim.toString successfully and the sms is not sent i check with ngrok the response is empty but when i call outside user.find the sms is sent the response is not empty

Comment: It is not simple. You can't make it work and I can't understand your question. Can you edit your question to show me what you're trying to do, with all the code. Please don't hide code behind requires as it makes it hard to understand for me.

Comment: if you dont mind give your email to give the whole code i cant put it all here is too long

Comment: Sure, email me at philnash@twilio.com.

Comment: i sent you the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The problem in your code is that you are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code.

`User.findOne` is an asynchronous call, so calling the `getandreplay()` function within the result callback will mean it happens after the response is completed in your route.

What I suggest is that you `return` the message that you want to reply with from `getandreplay()` and use that to form a response to the incoming request. Like this:

```
function getandreplay(node) {
    if (node.outs.length > 0) {
        if (node.outs.includes(req.body.Body.toLowerCase())) {
            for (var i = 0; i < node.output.length; i++) {
                var el = node.output[i];
                if (req.body.Body.toLowerCase() == el[0]) {
                    req.session.lastnode = getnode(el[1]);
                    if (getnode(el[1]).outs.length == 0) {
                        req.session.destroy();
                        User.findOneAndUpdate({}, { $push: { users: userPhone } }, { safe: true, upsert: true }, function(user, err) {});
                    }
                    return getnode(el[1]).msg;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return node.msg
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you call `User.findOne()` you get the result from `getandreplay()` and send that back as the response:

```
User.findOne({}, function(err, user) {
    if (!user.users.includes(userPhone)) {
        twiml.message(getandreplay(mynode));
    }
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
    res.end(twiml.toString());
});
```

Note that here I am calling `res.end` within the callback function for `User.findOne()`.

Let me know if this helps at all.